# How to get a footer to stick to the end of my web page text?

Tags: html, css, footer

I got a huge problem on this website.-> http://www.webbon.ca/demo/dev/home/

The problem is simple. I just need to get the footer to stick to the end of the text. You can use inspect element or firebug to tell me which modification you made to get it to work fine.

Comment: Please use **full** URLs in questions (and answers); if I'm at work, I like to know roughly where I'm going and what to expect (so far as possible).

Comment: Do you realize you have a `reset.css` being loaded ***after*** two other files?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you're still having trouble after fixing the HTML validation errors and @KatieK's CSS doesn't fix it, you can always re-ask, but you'll probably do better if you can show some of the attempts you've tried and how they didn't work.

Comment: Yes this code is a pain. The website is almost done but I had this problem with the footer. I'm working on Magento and the website is really upside down. Next time, I'll make better layout for surrreee. But for the moment, I have reedited what another company tried to working on and failed.

Comment: By the way this is NOT the real website. The real one is, I thought it was only local, but here it is -> http://www.webbon.ca/dev

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple way to get a footer which sticks to the bottom of the page:

CSS:

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
html, body {height: 100%;}
#wrap {min-height: 100%;}
#main {
overflow:auto;
padding-bottom: 150px;
}  
#footer {
position: relative;
margin-top: -150px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #CCCCCC;
clear:both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">

<div id="main">
<h1>Content!</h1>
</div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
<p>I'm the footer.</p>
</div>
```

You can see more, and get specific fixes, at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html.

Comment: OK, did you actually look at the page in question? I'm pretty sure OP's not looking for a "sticky footer". The page is totally broken anyways, check it out in IE8 for example.

Comment: Yep, I did.  I wasn't absolutely positive what the OP was asking for, and I wasn't able to resolve everything on the page.  If my answer is useful - great!  If not, also no problem.

Comment: I know how to do that no problem. But in my code that's hard core. I'm using Magento from an old website and I can't reedit as you did above. I just want you to modification from dev bar and tell me what you did. I know the code doesn't make sens but the website is done after solving this. I appreciate your help !